Bidegree genus formula for curve in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$
I've been going through Dhruv Ranganathan's online notes trying to learn a first course in algebraic geometry. Currently we are looking at the theory of curves. By convention of the notes, these are assumed to be smooth, irreducible, projective curves. They are all over $\mathbb{C}$ although I think this should work over other fields. I have the following exercise in the final chapter:

Let F be a bihomogeneous polynomial of bidegree $(d_1; d_2)$ in in 4 variables $X_0;X_1$
and $Y_0; Y_1$. Assume that $V(F) \subset  \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is a curve $V$ . By adapting the
calculation for $\mathbb{P}^2$ from [Theorem 17.3], calculate the degree of the canonical divisor of $V$ and
deduce that the genus of $C$ is $(d_1 - 1)(d_2 - 1)$.

For reference, here is the method of 17.3 (pages 51 and 52) that should be adapted:

Here the product is implemented via the Segre embedding. I have access to Riemann-Roch, and know about divisors (e.g. finiteness theorem, bezout etc) and differentials (e.g. transcendence degree and freeness of $\Omega_{V,P}$, canonical divisor) but this is a first course in algebraic geometry and thus does not use for example sheaves or any scheme theory (though I plan to study this at some point in the future). I had a look at many questions on stackexchange for a way to do this, and in many texts (gathmann, hartshorne etc) but usually people solve this problem using the adjunction formula, which is not a part of my course.
There should be a way of adapting 17.3 using only algebraic geometry of this course, and not with adjunction formula or scheme theory.
My attempt:
First of all I work back from the answer using Riemann-Roch, so that I know (also reading the scheme theory solutions confirms) that the canonical divisor should have degree $d_1(d_2-2)+d_2(d_1-2)$. So I should aim to get this from the 17.3 method.
If I write the Segre variety as $V(Z_{00}Z_{11}-Z_{01}Z_{10})$ then I think the subvariety of this that I'm working with in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is further generated by $F(Z_{i0},Z_{i1},Z_{0j},Z_{1j})$ for $i,j \in \{1,2\}$. (possibly some redundancy here, unsure).
Part I If I'm just looking at points on the affine patch where $Z_{00} \neq 0$ then I set $z_{ij}=Z_{ij}/Z_{00}$, and use $f(z_{01},z_{10})=F(1,z_{01},1,z_{10})$, ie using $i=j=0$ and setting $Z_{00}=1$. Then differentiating gives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_{01}}(z_{01},z_{10})dz_{01}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_{10}}(z_{01},z_{10})dz_{10}=0$, so perhaps I want to use $$\omega = \frac{dz_{01}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_{10}}(z_{01},z_{10})}=-\frac{dz_{10}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_{01}}(z_{01},z_{10})}$$
Part II To calculate for some $P$ in a patch I need to first know a local parameter to use. In the affine patch $V_{00} \subset \{Z_{00} \neq 0\}$, if I use $T$ for co-ordinates, the variety is cut out by $(T_{11}-T_{01}T_{10})$ and $f(T_{01},T_{10})$
Linearising those polynomials at $P=(P_{01},P_{10},P_{11}$ gives (respectively) $(T_{11}-P_{11})-P_{10}(T_{01}-P_{01})-P_{01}(T_{10}-P_{10})$ and $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{01}}(P))(T_{01}-P_{01})+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{10}}(P))(T_{10}-P_{10})$.
Thus it is the case that $$T_{P,V_{00}}=\{ (T_{11}-P_{11})-P_{10}(T_{01}-P_{01})-P_{01}(T_{10}-P_{10})=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{01}}(P))(T_{01}-P_{01})+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{10}}(P))(T_{10}-P_{10})=0 \} $$
We can assume WLOG (by smoothness) that one of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{10}}(P)$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{01}}(P)$ is nonzero, say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{01}}(P) \neq 0$.
The maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{V_{00},P}$ can be written as
$$[(T_{11}-P_{11})-P_{10}(T_{01}-P_{01})-P_{01}(T_{10}-P_{10})]\mathcal{O}_{V_{00},P} + [(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{01}}(P))(T_{01}-P_{01})+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_{10}}(P))(T_{10}-P_{10})] \mathcal{O}_{V_{00},P} + [T_{10}-P_{10}] \mathcal{O}_{V_{00},P}$$
One can then show by Nakayama's Lemma that in this case the local parameter is $\pi_{P}=(T_{10}-P_{10})$. (a similar argument would work if it had been the other partial derivative that was non-zero).
Okay, so looking at $\omega$, we have
$$v_P(\omega)=v_P(-\frac{dz_{10}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_{01}}(z_{01},z_{10})})=0$$
Since ${\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z_{01}}(z_{01},z_{10})}$ is nonvanishing (by the "WLOG" choice) and regular (it is a polynomial), hence as unit of $\mathcal{O}_{V_{00},P}$, and also because $dz_{10}=d\pi_P$.
Part III This is where I really struggle. I've tried a few ways to express the differential in terms of new differentials on a patch and relate them and calculate but it's not working for me. Perhaps I chose the wrong differential at the start, though it seemed like the "obvious" choice. I also didn't find a way yet to use the trick of excluding some bad points by choosing co-ordinates. I'm completely stuck, after having worked at this for days, and would appreciate help.
I feel like I've understood 17.3 properly, and I know how to use Riemann–Roch to get genus from canonical divisor. But I'm not really sure if any of what I've done so far is in the right direction though, or how to adapt the proof of the theorem any further.
Happy to expand on any parts, or answer questions to help.
Thanks,
Daniel

What are you allowed to use? Do you know Riemann-Hurwitz?

I have that too yes, though i think i only need riemann roch (to go from the canonical divisor to the genus). But no scheme theory.

I'm using Dhruv Ranganathan's online notes here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dr508/AGIINotes.pdf

The first issue here is that your setup isn't quite right. A curve of degree five and genus two in $\Bbb P^3$ must lie on a unique (smooth) quadric surface, but your setup would imply that it must be of even degree, since it would be the complete intersection of the quadric surface and $F(\dots)$. Instead, curves on $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$ are cut out by bi-homogeneous polynomials, i.e. global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1}(d_1,d_2)=p_1^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}(d_1)\otimes p_2^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}(d_2)$. Once you make that change, things should fall in to place pretty easily (though this method is longer than adjunction).
Fix coordinates $x_0,x_1$ on the first copy of $\Bbb P^1$ and coordinates $y_0,y_1$ on the second copy of $\Bbb P^1$. Let $F(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1)$ be an bihomogeneous polynomial cutting out a smooth divisor $V=V(F)$ of degree $(d_1,d_2)$ in $\Bbb P^1$, and if necessary change coordinates so that $[0:1]\times[0:1]$ is not in $V$. We'll show that $K_V = (d_1-2)L_1 + (d_2-2)L_2$ where $L_1$ is the equivalence class of $(\Bbb P^1\times\{pt\})\cap V$ and $L_2$ is the equivalence class of $(\{pt\}\times\Bbb P^1)\cap V$. This will show that the degree of $K_V$ is $(d_1-2)d_2+(d_2-2)d_1$.
We begin similarly to the proof in your post. Setting $x=X_1/X_0$ and $y=Y_1/Y_0$ and $f(X,Y)=F(1,X,1,Y)$, we see $f(x,y)=0$. Let $$\omega = \frac{dx}{(\partial f/\partial x)(x,y)} = \frac{-dy}{(\partial f/\partial y)(x,y)}$$ and we'll show $\operatorname{div}\omega = (d_1-2)V(X_0) + (d_2-2)V(Y_0)$ which will prove the claim.
Following step II in the linked proof, we make a calculation in $\Bbb A^2 = D_+(X_0) \times D_+(Y_0) \subset \Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$, and the exact same logic shows that $\omega$ is regular in $\Bbb A^2$, so its support is contained in the union of the two lines at infinity, $V(X_0)$ and $V(Y_0)$.
Now we calculate on the two lines at infinity, $V(X_0)$ and $V(Y_0)$. Since $[0:1]\times[0:1]$ is not in $V$, we can work on the patch $D(X_1)\times D(Y_0)$ to look at the behavior on $V(X_0)$ and similarly $D(X_0)\times D(Y_1)$ to look at the behavior on $V(Y_0)$. Starting with $D(X_1)\times D(Y_0)$, we pick coordinates $x'=X_0/X_1=1/x$ and $y=Y_1/Y_0$, set $g(X,Y)=F(X,1,1,Y)$ so that $f(x',y)=0$ and choose a new differential $$\eta = \frac{dx'}{(\partial g/\partial x')(x',y)} = \frac{-dy}{(\partial g/\partial y)(x',y)}$$ which is distinct from $\omega$. The same argument shows that $\eta$ is regular on $D(X_1)\times D(Y_0)$. Since $f(X,Y)=X^{d_1}g(1/X,Y)$, we have $\partial f/\partial X =  X^{d_1}(\partial g/\partial Y)(1/X,Y)$, giving $$\omega = \frac{dx}{(\partial f/\partial x)(x,y)} = \frac{(x')^{-2}dx'}{x^{d_1}(\partial g/\partial Y)(x',y)} = (x')^{d_1-2}\eta.$$ Hence by the same logic as in the linked proof, we find that the multiplicity of $(\omega)$ along $V(X_0)$ is $d_1-2$, and repeating the same proof but interchanging the $X$ and $Y$ variables gives that the multiplicity of $(\omega)$ along $V(Y_0)$ is $d_2-2$, so $(\omega)=(d_1-2)V(X_0) + (d_2-2)V(Y_0)$.

This is really helpful! Questions:

Is $D(X)=D_{+}(X)={X=0}$?
I'm unfamiliar with paragraph 1 concepts, but happy to accept I could have misapplied products via Segre (the only way I know). Are you saying I have (in "setup")?
For a plane curve, I can show $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \neq 0$ at $P$ then $x-P_x$ is a local parameter using Nakayama's Lemma. How does one get the corresponding result for product of varieties, necessary for calculating valuation in your proof.



$D(X)$ is where $X\neq 0$. 2. You're perfectly correct that the Segre embedding implements products, but we need to do something slightly different here than what the Segre embedding does - we need to be able to consider bihomogeneous polynomials which have different degrees in the different variable sets, but the Segre embedding enforces the same degree. 3. The same calculation will work: on $D(X_i)\times D(Y_i)$, you're working in $\Bbb A^2$ and so you can use everything you know about plane curves.


Thanks, I've accepted now. But I'm not seeing what you mean about Segre. $F$ being bihomogeneous $(d_1,d_2)$ then for $((a_0,a_1),(b_0,b_1))\in\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{P}$ don't we have: $F(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1)=0\iff a_i^{d_2}b_j^{d_1}F(a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1)=0\forall i,j\iff F(a_0b_j,a_1b_j,a_ib_0,a_ib_1)=0\forall i,j$? So aren't we asking for points on the Segre variety, $V(Z_{00}Z_{11}-Z_{01}Z_{10})$, where we further require $F_{ij}:=F(Z_{0j},Z_{1j},Z_{i0},Z_{i1})=0\forall i,j$? This seems like a valid variety with no necessity for $d_1=d_2$, since the $F_{ij}$ are homogeneous (of degree $d_1+d_2$).

Under the ring homomorphism $k[Z_{ij}] \to k[X_0,X_1,Y_0,Y_1]$, by $Z_{ij}\mapsto X_iY_j$, does anything map to $X_0^2Y_1^3$? No, because the $X$-degree and the $Y$-degree of the image of each $Z_{ij}$ are both 1, so the $X$-degree and the $Y$-degree of anything in the image are the same. But $X_0^2Y_1^3$ (and many other bihomogeneous polynomials we'd like to think about!) aren't in the image, and the key for making the argument work here is to find a single polynomial in the variables $X,Y$ defining our curve in $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$, which could be one of those polynomials.
